# How to get time from datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have datetime `30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM` here needed only time that is `9:25:52 AM` .this time i wanted to insert in `mysql` database and this field has data type time.

my code is :

```
<?php
$date = "30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM";
$date = strtotime($date);
echo date('H:i:s', $date);
?>
```

when execute it returns:

```
01:00:00
```

i am not getting where is the problem.Can any one help me on this.

thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do the OOP way

```
<?php
$date1="30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM";
$format = 'd-m-Y H:i:s A';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date1);
echo $date->format('H:i:s A') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$s = '30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM';
$dt = new DateTime($s);

$date = $dt->format('d-m-Y');
$time = $dt->format('h:i:s A');

echo $time;
```

see details here http://docs.php.net/class.datetime

Answer (score 5):

actually the code does exactly what you want

```
<?php
 $date = "30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM";
 $date = strtotime($date);
 echo date('H:i:s', $date);
?>
```

[demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c3a-jvr)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

```
$date = "1899-12-30 9:25:52 AM";

echo $start_time = date("h:i:s A", strtotime($date));
```

OR

```
$date = "30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM";
$dtime = new DateTime($date);
echo $dtime->format("h:i:s A");
```

Answer (score 1):

You get `01:00:00` as result, because on your version of PHP, [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) function returns invalid integer. More likely value `false` is returned, and when you format `false` via [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function, you will get `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. You get time `01:00:00` because you have timezone offset, you are probably in `UTC+1` timezone.

**[Here](http://3v4l.org/kVumc)** you can see, that your code will not work correctly on PHP version bellow `5.2.6`, even on x64 machines, and results will be unreliable.

Best option would be to upgrade your PHP version (or change webhosting). But if you do not have this options, you can use string functions to break and concatenate date & time parts, **[like this](http://3v4l.org/Arn1K)**:

```php
$date = "30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM";
sscanf($date, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d %s", $d, $m, $Y, $g, $i, $s, $A);
$h = $A == 'AM' ? $g : $g + 12;
echo "$Y-$m-$d $h:$i:$s";  # 1899-12-30 9:25:52
echo "$h:$i:$s";           # 9:25:52
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `explode` like

```
$date = "30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM";
$date_arr = explode(' ',$date);
echo $date_arr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be alternative

```
<?php
$date = "30-12-1899 9:25:52 AM";
$date = explode(' ',$date);
echo date[1].' '.date[2];
?>
```